# More examples of an extension of Frullani, finishing with the evaluation of a limit or asymptotic

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, improper-integrals, examples-counterexamples

I did the specialization from [1] of the extension of Frullani theorem FRU2, for the inverse tangent, with $a_j$ the $jth$ prime number, and weights $m_1=1$ and $m_j=-1/(n-1)$ for (odd primes) $2\leq j\leq n $.

Then if there are no mistakes in my calculations, using the Prime Number Theorem for the [first Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) from

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan(2x)-\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{j=2}^n \arctan(p_jx)}{x} dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\log 2-\frac{1}{n-1}\left(\vartheta(n)-\log 2\right)\right),$$
that holds for $n\geq 3$, one has the asymptotic equivalence 
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan(2x)-\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{j=2}^n \arctan(p_jx)}{x} dx\sim\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\log 2-1\right)$$ as $n\to\infty.$

I would like to know more examples as mine, and if you find some mistake in my calculations please say me:

> **Question.** Can you show us a different example of such extension of Frullani theorem FRU2, for a function satisfying the hyphotesis and yourself sequences $a_j$ and $m_j$, and also 
>   finishing your example with the evaluation of a limit or an asymptotic? Please also if you find some mistake in my example tell me. **Many thanks.**

---

[1]  G.J.O. Jameson, [*The Frullani integrals*](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/frullani.pdf), Lancaster University.

Comment: I hope that some user want to add his/her approach to get an statement by means of the same trick, combining Frullani with an asymptotic/limit. Only is required the final result or the guideline to get it. Many thanks.

Comment: You have noticed that a simpler variant of the same example is found by taking just $a_j = j$ instead of $p_j$. Reversing the signs of $m_j$, to make it positive, I think we get ${\pi\over2}{{\log n!}\over{n - 1}}$. By Stirling's formula (or more easily by simple integral estimation), this sum is asymptotic to ${\pi\over2}(\log n - 1)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your very nice example @GlenWeyl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your maths seem right to me. You may build a lot of examples. Consider $a_{j}=\exp\left(\mu^{2}\left(j\right)\right)
 $, take $m_{j}=-\frac{1}{j}
 $ for $j=1,\dots,n-1
 $, $m_{n}=H_{n-1}
 $ where $H_{l}
 $ is the $l$-th harmonic number and $f\left(x\right)=e^{-x}
 $. We get $$I_{n}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n-1}e^{-\exp\left(\mu^{2}\left(n\right)\right)x}-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}e^{-\exp\left(\mu^{2}\left(j\right)\right)x}/j}{x}dx=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{\mu^{2}\left(j\right)}{j}-H_{n-1}\mu^{2}\left(n\right).
 $$ Now we recall that the counting function of the squarefree number has the asymptotic $$Q\left(x\right)=\sum_{j\leq x}\mu^{2}\left(j\right)=\frac{6}{\pi^{2}}x+O\left(\sqrt{x}\right)
 $$ hence using [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we have $$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{\mu^{2}\left(j\right)}{j}=\frac{Q\left(n-1\right)}{n-1}+\int_{1}^{n-1}\frac{Q\left(t\right)}{t^{2}}dt
 $$ $$=\frac{6}{\pi^{2}}\log\left(n-1\right)+O\left(1\right)
 $$ hence $$I_{n}=\frac{6}{\pi^{2}}\log\left(n-1\right)-H_{n-1}\mu^{2}\left(n\right)+O\left(1\right)
 $$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

**Note**: this example has nothing special. As I wrote you may build by yourself a lot of identities.

Comment: Seems very nice, I will study in next hours, and of course is special because you wrote it. Good afternoon and thanks.